# How to convert geojson object to KML in angular

Tags: angular, geojson, kml

I need to convert my geojson object to kml file in my angular project. Over some reearch I found this npm library [geojson-to-kml](https://github.com/bryik/geojson-to-kml#readme). But problem which i am facing when I am trying to use this . I m getting an error

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'geojson-to-kml'.

I have tried installing with `npm i  @types/geojson-to-kml` but its of no use throwing an error ERR 404  '@types/geojson-to-kml@*' is not in this registry.

Is there any way I can use this library in my angular project. Or is there any other way which will help me to convert geojson object to kml file.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error locally. First I needed to install the `@types/node`

```
npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

then change the way tokml is defined:

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
const tokml = require('tokml');

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  geoObject = {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [125.6, 10.1],
    },
    properties: {
      name: 'Dinagat Islands',
    },
  };
  kmlObject = tokml(this.geoObject);

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.kmlObject);
  }
}
```

Lastly, add the node type to `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Even in your starblitz its getting error `Cannot find module 'tokml' or its corresponding type declarations.` after build

Comment: check the console log, you will see the kml object there even tho you see the error.

Comment: Because of that error project is not getting build.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/mapbox/tokml not the one you are using. does that make a difference?

Comment: see the latest changes I made to the answer.